# Не выводит название города работая с Map Java

Tags: java, map

Исходные данные:

```
 Map<String, Integer> cityCount = new HashMap<>();
        cityCount.put("Omsk", 1300);
        cityCount.put("Kiev", 5700);
        cityCount.put("Marino", 2200);
        cityCount.put("Moscow", 12400);
        cityCount.put("Mexico", 20500);
```

**key**- *города*, **value**- *численность* людей в этих городах.

По тексту задачи нужно вывести город с самой большой численностью людей. В моем случае это **Mexico** со значением *20500*.
В моем коде отображаются цифры, но при выводе названия города выходит *Null*

Вот что написал:

```
Set<String> keys = cityCount.keySet();
int maxCity = 0;
for (String key : keys) {
    if (cityCount.get(key) >= maxCity) {
        maxCity = cityCount.get(key);
    }
}
System.out.println("Большое количество население в городе: " + cityCount.get(keys));
```

И вот такой результат выдает мне:

```
Большое количество население в городе: null
```

Как можно вывести теперь сам город* **Mexico**?

Comment: На ваше ``cityCount.get(keys)`` IDE пишет предупреждение, что 'Map<String, Integer>' may not contain keys of type 'Set<String>'

Comment: Не знаю, у меня IDE не выдает предупреждение, а выводит null

Comment: Это когда вы запускаете код, то выводит null, а окне с кодом это место подсвечивается. По крайней мере в IntellijIDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать таким способом

```c
String maxCity = "";
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> city : cityCount.entrySet()) {
    if(city.getValue() > max) {
               max = city.getValue();
               maxCity = city.getKey();
            }
}
    
System.out.println("Большое количество население в городе: " + maxCity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Оно и правильно. У вас нет ключа, который являет собой сет из названий городов. Т.к. `keys` у вас набор названий городов, то `cityCount.get(keys)` эквивалентно `cityCount.get([Omsk, Mexico, Kiev, Marino, Moscow])`. Понятно, что вернется `null`.

Сделайте еще одну переменную для города, и сохраняйте туда название, как только найден очередной максимум.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Stream API, в частности метод [`Stream::max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-), где в качестве компаратора для элементов мапы можно использовать компаратор по значению [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--):

```java
Map<String, Integer> cityCount = new HashMap<>();
cityCount.put("Omsk", 1300);
cityCount.put("Kiev", 5700);
cityCount.put("Marino", 2200);
cityCount.put("Moscow", 12400);
cityCount.put("Mexico", 20500);

System.out.println(cityCount.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // Optional<String>
    .orElse("N/A")
);
// -> Mexico
```